# How do I consume SkyBiometry's faces/detect by POSTing a multipart jpeg request?

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data

I want to write a request to the [SkyBiometry API](https://skybiometry.com/documentation), and pass the faces/detect endpoint multiple files from my filesystem. The [documentation](https://skybiometry.com/documentation/#document-19) states that the images should be a MIME multi-part message, where each argument is a separate chunk of form data.

I'm pretty new to using express and programming and general, and I was wondering whether what I'm doing is correct.

```
request.post(
{ 
        url: 'http://api.skybiometry.com/fc/faces/detect.json?api_key=MYKEY', 
        form: {
            files: [
                fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/images/img1.jpg'),
                fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/images/img2.jpg')
            ]
        }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

I'm getting a 402 - MISSING ARGUMENTS error, and it says I'm missing either urls or files. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?